# SQL Server commands to clear caches before running a performance comparison

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-testing

When comparing the execution time of two different queries, it's important to clear the cache to make sure that the execution of the first query does not alter the performance of the second.

In a Google Search, I could find these commands:

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

In fact, my queries are taking a more realistic time to complete after several executions than before. However, I'm not sure this is the recommended technique.

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Personally, for a common query the 2nd and subsequent executions matter more.

Are you testing disk IO or query performance?

Assuming your query runs often and is critical, then you want to measure that under real life conditions. And you don't want to clear prod server caches each time...

If you want, you can:

- `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` clears clean (unmodified) pages from the buffer pool
   Precede that with a `CHECKPOINT` to flush any dirty pages to disk first
- `DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB` clears execution plans for that database

Also see (on DBA.SE)

- [Solving high page load time using SQL Profiler](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7859/630)

Comment: Got an error when running `DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB`: An incorrect number of parameters was given to the DBCC statement.

Comment: Finally found it:
`DECLARE @myDb AS INT = DB_ID();
DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB(@myDb);
GO`
from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962789/entity-framework-cached-query-plan-performance-degrades-with-different-parameter

Answer (score 16):

*Late answer but may be of use to other readers*

`DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` is an often used command for query testing and gauging query execution speed. This command (when run) leaves behind only the dirty pages, which is actually a small portion of data. It removes all the clean pages for an entire server.

Be advised that this command should *not* be run on production environment. Running this command will result in mostly empty buffer cache. Running any query after executing the `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` command, will use physical reads to bring back the data into the cache, which is very likely going to be a lot slower than memory.

Again, treat this command similarly to `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` - it should not be run on any production server unless you absolutely know what you are doing.

This can be a useful development tool because you can run a query in a performance testing environment over and over without any changes in speed/efficiency due to caching of data in memory.

Learn more at: http://www.sqlshack.com/insight-into-the-sql-server-buffer-cache/

Answer (score 13):

I was always told to use:

```
dbcc dropcleanbuffers;
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx):

> Use DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS to test queries with a cold buffer cache
>   without shutting down and restarting the server.
>
> To drop clean buffers from the buffer pool, first use CHECKPOINT to
>   produce a cold buffer cache. This forces all dirty pages for the
>   current database to be written to disk and cleans the buffers. After
>   you do this, you can issue DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS command to remove all
>   buffers from the buffer pool.

Comment: Plus: `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to clear any cached execution plans...

Comment: Only if you want to test IO, surely...

Answer (score 5):

Edit: the OP's question is about *caches,* and the use of commands such as `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`, which clears stored execution plans.  Apparently I didn't have my glasses on, because my answer addressed *buffers,* which is to say recently-read data stored in memory for quick retrieval.  Hopefully this is still of use to someone.

---

The other answers are correct about reasons to *not* run `[DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS][1]`.  However, there are also a couple of reasons to do so:

1: Consistency

If you want to compare two different queries or procedures which are attempting to do the same thing in different ways, they're likely to hit the same pages.  If you naively run query #1 then query #2, the second may be much faster simply because those pages were cached by the first query.  If you clear the cache before each execution, they start on an even footing.

If you do want to test hot-cache performance, be sure to run the queries several times, alternating, and discard the first couple of runs.  Average the results.

2: Worst-case performance

Say you have a query which takes one second against a hot cache but one minute against a cold cache.  An optimization which makes the in-memory query 20% slower but the IO-bound query 20% faster could be a big win: no one will care about the extra 200 ms of run time under normal circumstances, but if something forces a query to run against disk, taking 48 seconds instead of 60 is material.  It might be enough to save a sale.

This is less of a concern on modern systems with tens of gigabytes of memory, and relatively fast SAN and SSD storage, but it still matters.  If some analyst runs a massive table scan query against your OLTP database which wipes out half of your buffer cache, storage-efficient queries will get you back up to speed sooner.

Comment: Thanks for merging together the difference pieces of advice into a cohesive answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Good point!  I will edit to clarify, though this answer is arguably irrelevant to OP's specific question, now that you've brought my attention to exactly what they've asked.